# JavaScript: Adding recursion result to array and return it

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have a nested object and my goal is to get the path until a key-value pair matches in an array.

My current implementation implements this by strings and concatinating the stringts with da dot (".").

However, instead of that I would like to add all the interim results to the array and push to it. But somehow this does not work.

**Code with example Data**

---

```
const data = [
    {
        parentId: "1111",
        name: "Audi",
        children : [
            {
                parentId: "2222",
                name: "Benz",
                children : [
                    {
                        parentId: "3333",
                        name: "VW",
                        children : [
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]




const pathTo = (array, target) => {
    var result;
    array.some(({ parentId, name, children = [] }) => {
        if (parentId === target) {
            return result = JSON.stringify({"parentId" : parentId, "name" : name});
        }
        var temp = pathTo(children, target)
        if (temp) {
            return result = JSON.stringify({"parentId" : parentId, "name" : name}) + "." + temp;
        }
    });
    return result;
};


console.log(pathTo(data, "3333"))
```

**Current Result**

---

```
{"parentId":"1111","name":"Audi"}.{"parentId":"2222","name":"Benz"}.{"parentId":"3333","name":"VW"}
```

=> The Path concatenated with a string. But I would like :

**Expected Result**

---

```
[ "{"parentId":"1111","name":"Audi"}", "{"parentId":"2222","name":"Benz"}"{"parentId":"3333","name":"VW"}"]
```

=> an array with all the elements in subsequent order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return an array or `undefined`.

```js
const
    data = [{ parentId: "1111", name: "Audi", children : [{ parentId: "2222", name: "Benz", children : [{ parentId: "3333", name: "VW", children : [] }] }] }],
    pathTo = (array, target) => {
        let result;
        array.some(({ parentId, name, children = [] }) => {
            if (parentId === target) {
                result = [{ parentId: parentId, name: name }];
                return true;
            }
            const temp = pathTo(children, target)
            if (temp) {
                result = [{ parentId: parentId, name: name }, ...temp];
                return true;
            }
        });
        return result;
    };

console.log(pathTo(data, "3333"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: seems to be right, thank you. One question: You are definig the const data, then follows a comma (","), then you add the function name "pathTo" without a "const", "var", or "let". How is this notation called?

Comment: it is just standard to declare and initialize multiple variables/constants with one statement (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#syntax). it applies as well to `var` and `let` (both works without value as well). i do not know, if it has a special name

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to break problems like this into pieces and make at least some of it more generic in the process.

```js
function * traversePaths (xs, path = []) {
  for (let x of xs) {
    const newPath = [...path, x]
    yield newPath
    yield * traversePaths (x .children || [], newPath)
  }
}

const deepFindPath = (pred) => (xs) => {
  for (let path of traversePaths (xs)) {
    if (pred (path [path.length - 1])) {return path} 
  }
}

const pathByParentId = (target) =>
  deepFindPath (({parentId}) => parentId == target)

const data = [{parentId: "1111", name: "Audi", children : [{parentId: "2222", name: "Benz", children : [{parentId: "3333", name: "VW", children : []}]}]}]


// stringified to avoid SO's `/**id:4**/` - `/**ref:4**/,` notation
console .log (JSON .stringify ( 
  pathByParentId ('3333') (data)
, null, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here `traversePaths` is a generator function that takes any array whose elements have (optional, and recursive) `children` properties, and traverses it (preorder) yielding a array of object/sub-objects nodes for each path in the array.

`deepFindPath` returns the path to the first node that matches the predicate supplied.

These two functions are generic.  Then to solve your problem we write the simple `pathByParentId`, which simply accepts a target id and passes to `deepFindPath` a function which tests if the node's `parentId` property matches that target id.  It will return the path to the first matching node, or `undefined` if nothing matches.

Your requested output matched the above, except that you didn't mention the `children` nodes.  I prefer this return, just simple references to the existing nodes.  But if you really don't want the children, then you can just do:

```js
const pathByParentId = (target) => (
  data, 
  res = deepFindPath (({parentId}) => parentId == target) (data)
) => res && res .map (({children, ...rest}) => rest)
```

While we *could* do this in the traversal function, it would make that function less generic and probably less helpful.  But if you wanted to do so, you could keep the original version of `pathByParentId` and replace `traversePaths` with this:

```js
function * traversePaths (xs, path = []) {
  for (let {children, ...rest} of xs) {
    const newPath = [...path, rest]
    yield newPath
    yield * traversePaths (children || [], newPath)
  }
}
```

This is less flexible than the previous version, but it still generically lists the paths to any array whose elements have (optional, and recursive) `children` properties. The elements in those lists are new objects, similar to the original but missing the `children` properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using a dependency, I'd do that instead. Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const data = [{ parentId: '1111', name: 'Audi', children: [{ parentId: '2222', name: 'Benz', children: [{ parentId: '3333', name: 'VW', children: [] }] }] }];

const find = (obj, v) => objectScan(['**'], {
  abort: true,
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === v,
  rtn: ({ parents }) => parents
    .filter((p) => !Array.isArray(p))
    .reverse()
    .map(({ parentId, name }) => ({ parentId, name }))
})(obj);

console.log(find(data, '3333'));
/* => [
  { parentId: '1111', name: 'Audi' },
  { parentId: '2222', name: 'Benz' },
  { parentId: '3333', name: 'VW' }
] */
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)